# Find information about newest element in XQuery

Tags: xpath, xquery

I have a xml file like this:

```
 <carSchema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="carSchema.xsd">
 <car>
    <License>23</License>
    <year>2010</year>
    <model>a</model>
    <manufacturer>hyundai</manufacturer>
</car>
<car>
    <License>24</License>
    <year>2002</year>
    <model>b</model>
    <manufacturer>hyundai</manufacturer>
</car>
<car>
    <License>25</License>
    <year>2005</year>
    <model>c</model>
    <manufacturer>hyundai</manufacturer>
</car>
<car>
    <License>26</License>
    <year>2004</year>
    <model>d</model>
</car>
<car>
    <License>27</License>
    <year>2016</year>
    <model>f</model>
    <manufacturer>hyundai</manufacturer>
</car>
```

I want to find information about newest car in Xquery. I wrote this Query that return year of newest car.

```
 xquery version "1.0";
 max(
 for $x in doc("car.xml")/carSchema/car
   order by $x/year descending
 return $x/year)
```

How I return all information about that car(License, model, manufacturer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(for $car in doc("car.xml")/carSchema/car
order by $car/year descending
return $car)[1]/*
```

to find all child elements of the element with the latest year or

```
(for $car in doc("car.xml")/carSchema/car
order by $car/year descending
return $car)[1]
```

to find the element itself with the latest year.